# Populating xml elements representitave of a table structure containing a header and body

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to build a xml structure that represents a table with rows and cells using linq to xml. Example:

```
<table>
    <tablerow>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell></cell>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell></cell>
        </tablerow>
</table>
```

The first row serves as a header and the second row contains the field value. Within the object I am pulling the names from the names are the same

I am trying to figure out the best approach to add the field name to both tablerow cells so that 
I have an output as

```
<table>
    <tablerow>
        <cell>Field1</cell>
        <cell>Field2</cell>
        <cell>Field3</cell>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
        <cell>Field1</cell>
        <cell>Field2</cell>
        <cell>Field3</cell>
    </tablerow>
</table>
```

I am currently retrieving all the cell Elements

```
var cells = doc.Descendants(tablerow).Descendants(cell);
```

and then using a foreach to insert using a normal `.add()`

```
foreach (c in cells)
{
  c.add(//XElement content...);
}
```

My question is if I only have 3 fields (but 6 cells) what would be the best approach for  populating them into the 6 cells. 
I generate the cells dynamically so I can control and ensure that there will always
be one cell for each field in each row.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or ideas

-Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like so:

```
var fieldNames = new[] { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" };
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:/somewhere.xml").Root;

foreach (var row in doc.Elements("tablerow"))
{
    var i=0;  // index into fieldNames array
    foreach (var cell in row.Elements("cell"))
    {
        cell.Add(new XText(fieldNames[i++]));  // take one, and increment
    }
}
doc.Save("c:/somewhere.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you can create it from scratch using:

```
var fieldNames = new[] { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" };

var doc = new XElement("table");
doc.Add(CreateTableRowElement(fieldNames));
doc.Add(CreateTableRowElement(fieldNames));
doc.Save("c:/file.xml");
```

and the helper function

```
private XElement CreateTableRowElement(string[] fieldNames)
{
    return new XElement("tablerow", fieldNames.Select(name => 
        new XElement("cell", new XText(name))));
}
```

Comment: In this implementation the rows already exist. I need to detect the cells and then insert the fields. I see what you are suggesting but it doesn't work for this implementation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CSJ for guiding me in the right direction his answer is the correct answer but I wanted to share my code as my implementation was just a tad different. Here is the full working sample I mocked up in a console app. - Cheers

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xd = CreateXml();
            List<string> stuff = GeneratList();
            PopulateArray(stuff, xd);
        }

        private static XDocument PopulateArray(List<string>mylist, XDocument xmlFile)
        {
            var row = xmlFile.Descendants("tablerow");

            foreach (var r in row)
            {
                var i = 0;
                var cell = r.Descendants("cell");
                foreach (var c in cell)
                {
                    c.Add(new XText(mylist[i++]));
                }
            }
            return xmlFile;
        }

        private static XDocument CreateXml()
        {
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("table",
                    new XElement("tablerow",
                        new XElement("cell"),
                        new XElement("cell"),
                        new XElement("cell")
                    ),
                new XElement("tablerow",
                        new XElement("cell"),
                        new XElement("cell"),
                        new XElement("cell")
                    )           
                )     
                );
            return doc;
        }

        private static List<string> GenerateList()
        {
            return new List<string> {
                "Orange",
                "Grape",
                "Banana"
            };
        }
```